# Is there a term for people who make excuses for an exception that their own actions necessitate?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Like how Taylor Swift fans say that she needs to take private jets because fans would make her taking public transport untenable. So it's the fans themselves that are the reason for her behaviour, which they are making excuses for. Is there a term for such people, or for what they are doing?

An example of how it could be used:

Fans are (creating the exceptional need for an excuse they are making) Taylor Swift's use of private jets'

or something like that.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148051/discussion-on-question-by-user14094230-is-there-a-term-for-people-who-make-excus); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible description is

> **self-justification**
>
> a reason, excuse, or explanation that you give for your behaviour or actions

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-justification).